# PSQL was inferring schema, but how?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

We're in the process of upgrading our software from PostgreSQL 9.2 to 9.6 and we've run into an odd issue.

Our installation runs an SQL script to create the database. This is done using `psql -f`. This worked fine under 9.2 but seems to have issues with not creating objects in 9.6. I've been looking into this and found something odd in the SQL script. Most of the tables are created using statements that look like this:

```
--
-- Name: crawler_run; Type: TABLE; Schema: analytics; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS crawler_run (
    ... columns, etc.
);

--
ALTER TABLE analytics.crawler_run OWNER TO postgres;
```

Note that there is no schema in the `create table` statement. But the tables were being created in the correct schema and the subsequent `alter table` statement was not failing.

My best guess is that the preceding comment has something to do with it, but I've not been able to find any documentation to support that.

So how was this working?

Comment: Don't know why it worked for you in before, but when you create the table you should create it to correct schema in the first place or before altering owner rights in specific schema need to alter the schema first. Shortly: maybe 9.2 was more forgiving and it was fixed in 9.6, but however I would recommend changing your build script doing it correctly :)

Comment: Look for a [`SET search_path ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) statement in the beginning of your script.

Comment: @pozs You got it. The statement was pretty far above but that appears to be the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables are created in the first schema of the user/role [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH), which is either set permanently or just for the current session.

Look for a statement like:

```
SET search_path = analytics
```

In your case it was `analytics` and now it is probably back to the default `public`.

Comment: A link to the documentation and a quick explanation of what "search path" means would take this from a good answer to a great one. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH